# Optionally pass variables/params

Tags: javascript

I have multiple options and apparently, the third party api doesn't like when I try to pass variables that aren't defined. It'll give me a signature error!

what's required is `side`, `symbol`, `order_type`, `qty` and `time_in_force`

and that's what I'm passing in the example below

```
mutation {
  setActiveOrder(
    side: "Buy", 
    symbol: "BTCUSD", 
    order_type: "Market", 
    qty: 1, 
    time_in_force: "GoodTillCancel"
  ) {
      data
  }
}
```

but sometimes `(order_type === "Limit")` and `price` is required

sometimes there will be either or both `take_profit` and `stop_loss` for either of the two possibilities above.

that being said I'm trying to figure out the best way to optionally pass variables without writing if statements for every possibility the hard way

I'd love another perspective

```js
    settActiveOrder: async (
      _,
      {
        side,
        symbol,
        order_type,
        qty,
        price,
        time_in_force,
        take_profit,
        stop_loss,
        reduce_only,
        close_on_trigger,
        order_link_id,
      },
      ctx
    ) => {
      const setActiveOrder = async () => {
        try {
          return await cclient.placeActiveOrder({
            side: side,
            symbol: symbol,
            order_type: order_type,
            qty: qty,
            // price: price,
            time_in_force: time_in_force,
            // take_profit: take_profit,
            // stop_loss: stop_loss,
            // reduce_only: reduce_only,
            // close_on_trigger: close_on_trigger,
            // order_link_id: order_link_id,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      };
      const data = await setActiveOrder();
      return { data: data };
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to build a new object (as you do in your example), and the api doesn't handle 'undefined' values itself, then you do need a way of checking the input and build the object conditionally, but you can do it in a loop.

To clarify, here your code again, with comments:

```
settActiveOrder: async (
    _,
    // here you are using "object destructuring".
    // Not existing properties will become a valid,
    // existing variable with the value >>undefined<<
    { side, symbol, order_type, qty, /* ... */ }, 
    ctx
) => { 
    /* ... */

    // here your are building a new object,
    // possibly having existing properties with the value >>undefined<<,
    // but you want these properties to not exist
    return await cclient.placeActiveOrder({
        side: side,
        symbol: symbol,
        order_type: order_type,
        qty: qty,
        /* ... */
    });
    /* ... */
};
```

#### Solution:

you could reference the original object, instead of using object destructuring, and loop over its properties, e.g.:

```
settActiveOrder: async ( _, originalParams, ctx ) => { // <-- no object destructuring
    /* ... */

    // build new object in a loop, but skip undefined properties
    const passedParams = Object.keys( originalParams ).reduce(( acc, key ) => {
        if( typeof originalParams[ key ] === 'undefined' ){
            return acc;
        } else {
            return {
                ...acc,
                [key]: originalParams[ key ]
            }
        }
    }, {});

    return await cclient.placeActiveOrder( passedParams );
    /* ... */
});
```

#### Alternative solution:

In case you just need to pass all defined properties, and do not really have to build the object new, then you could simply pass the whole object as it is, instead of using the object destructuring.

Then the *not-existing-properties* will stay *not-existing-properties*, instead of becoming *existing-propterties-with-value-undefined*.

```
settActiveOrder: async ( _, originalParams, ctx ) => {
    /* ... */
    return await cclient.placeActiveOrder( originalParams );
    /* ... */
});
```

Comment: Your alternative solution worked best! This is a perfect example of me over complicating a rather simple solution. Thank you very much for taking your time to help me!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you won't avoid if statements,
but better approach than writing all combinations would be to declare dictionary and append prefered variables for request

Something like this:

```
var dictForRequest = {

        side: side,
        symbol: symbol,
        order_type: order_type,
        qty: qty,
        time_in_force: time_in_force,
 };
 if(wantPrice)
   dictForRequest["price"] = price;
 if(wantTakeProfit)
   dictForRequest["take_profit"] = take_profit;
 ....
```

Than pass `dictForRequest` to

```
       ...
      const setActiveOrder = async () => {
    try {
      return await cclient.placeActiveOrder(dictForRequest);        
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operators. which are if else statements but shorter and easier to write.

```
{
  price: price ? price : 0,
}

// The above code translates to:

if(price) {
  price = price
  } else {
    price = 0
  }
```

Also, with ES6 you don't necessarily have to write it like this:

```
{
  side: side,
  symbol: symbol,
  order_type: order_type,
}

// These two are the same. You can write it like below.

{
  side,
  symbol,
  order_type
}
```

The above code is valid as long as the name of the key and the variable name passed to the key as value are the same. JS can figure out and map the right value to the right key, but they must be named exactly the same. Also, this rule is case sensitive. So, price: Price is not the same. it has to be price: price for this rule to hold true.

If you are looking for another option apart from ternary operators, then you can initialize your variables when you declare them. But, initialize them with the let keyword instead of const. Since, const variables are immutable -> let price = 0;